# Чем отличается экземпляр класса от объекта класса?

Tags: ооп, objective-c, классы

Чем отличается экземпляр класса от объекта класса в objective-c?
Задали такой вопрос на собеседовании, я в недоумении ответил "Не понимаю вопроса, разве это не одно и то же?".
Просьба сильно не пинать, обж-си учил сам, в ускоренном темпе, и времени разбираться с самой концепцией не было.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Я думаю, Вы попали под раздачу из-за недостаточной квалификации собеседующего… если заниматься прямым переводом терминов, то можно много интересного узнать :).

В документации по Obj-C используются термины `class object` и `class instance`. Если их дословно перевести на русский, то получится как раз то, о чём Вас спрашивали. Причём в русском языке естественно `объект класса` считать его `экземпляром`. В то время, как совершено очевидно, что означает английский термин `class object` — этот объект, в котором хранится, так сказать, информация о классе.

> #### Class Objects
>
> A class definition contains various
>   kinds of information, much of it about
>   instances of the class:
>
> - The name of the class and its superclass
> - A template describing a set of instance variables
> - The declarations of method names and their return and argument types
> - The method implementations
>
> This information is compiled and
>   recorded in data structures made
>   available to the runtime system. The
>   compiler creates just one object, a
>   **class object**, to represent the class.
>   The class object has access to all the
>   information about the class, which
>   means mainly information about what
>   instances of the class are like. It’s
>   able to produce new instances
>   according to the plan put forward in
>   the class definition.
>
> Although a **class object** keeps the
>   prototype of a **class instance**,
>   *it’s not an instance itself*. It has no instance variables of its own and
>   it can’t perform methods intended for
>   instances of the class. However, a
>   class definition can include methods
>   intended specifically for the class
>   object—class methods as opposed to
>   instance methods. A class object
>   inherits class methods from the
>   classes above it in the hierarchy,
>   just as instances inherit instance
>   methods.

Comment: Я бы, наверное, лучше говорил не «объект класса», а «объект-класс».

Comment: Довольно интересно. Этот вопрос заставил меня задуматься.. в яве тоже есть такое, но почему-то я не могу припомнить какое-то особое название для экземпляров класса Class :)

Comment: Ну такое есть в любом истинно-ооп языке или в языке, косящем под истинно-ооп. Специальных русских названий я тоже не припомню… По поводу же этого — собственно, что спрашивают я догадался совершенно случайно :). Как я уже говрил, obj-c я в глаза не видел, так что стал читать доки с намерением найти какой-нибудь «серьёзный» ответ на вопрос. И вот случайно заметил такой каламбур с дословными переводами).

Comment: >> название для экземпляров класса Class

Метакласс ;)

Comment: class object  
class instance
Сокращаем class и получаем Объект  и его Экземпляр. Таким образом получается, что разница есть.

Comment: @Bimawa, что-то вы как-то мимо вообще...

Comment: @AlexDenisov мне, просто, кажется, что даже по русски Объект класса-это ну как то не правильно чтоли звучит.
т.е. Объект класса, я понимаю как Класс описывающий этот Объект (Допустим это соматическое описание клеток овечки Долли). 
А Экземпляр класса -  это как клон овечки Долли созданный по соматическому описанию Объекта (Долли). 
 В связи с этим, мне кажется собеседуюищй в полне квалифицирован.

Comment: Уже разобрались. Есть такое понятие как метакласс, а вот конкретные классы - это объекты типа "метакласс".

Просто ваша фраза "сокращаем class" как-то не в тему звучит...

Answer (score 5):

Если подходить с чисто утилитарной точки зрения, то в Objective-C вы можете для любого класа определить два типа методов:

1. Методы класса - начинаются с +  , иногда называются `singleton` -- по-русски и не выговорить.  Суть их в том, что для их вызова НЕ НУЖНО создавать экземпляр класса.

Примером может служить, например, [`UIColor greyColor`]. Объекты, полученные таким способом не требуют последующего освобождения механизмами управления памятью. В ряде случаев использование таких методов очень удобно.

1. Методы экземпляра объекта. - их объявление начинается с - . Это классические методы, которые работают только после того, когда вы создали объект с помощью alloc.

Вероятно, именно об этом вас и спрашивали на собеседовании :-)

Comment: Это методы объекта и методы класса, это не совсем то о чем меня спрашивали ;)

Comment: А это единственное, чем отличается объект класса и экземпляр класса - наборами методов, которые по-разному определяются и по-разному используются.

Comment: Немного уточню: singleton'ом называется метод, вызываемый для класса в целом, который возвращает уже инициализированный экземпляр этого класса. А так - вы все верно сказали.

Comment: Всю жизнь (как программиста) считал что синглтон это не метод, а способ (паттерн) позволяющий создать только один экземпляр объекта.

Comment: А так и есть, просто в Objective-C под синглтоном понимается не паттерн, а метод класса. Это просто специфический термин, возможно неудачный. Считается что метод класса как бы возвращает всегда один и тот же объект - отсюда и синглтон. То есть сколько раз мы не вызовем многострадальный [UIColor greyColor] - это будет один и тот же объект. И он используется обычно не для постоянного использования, а для того чтобы инициализировать обычные объекты, ну например:

UIColor *grey = [[UIColor alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor greyColor]];

Comment: Ну мне ведь никто не запрещает таким же образом вызывать/создавать методы которые ничего не возвращают, так что на мой взгляд это не самый удачный термин.

Comment: Я уж подумал что наверно плохо использовать методы класса которые не возвращают новый объект, типа говнокод пишу, но тут встретил

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector...]

и успокоился =)

Answer (score 3):

Объект класса содержит все статические свойства, а экземпляр класса содержит все не статические свойства. Объект класса инициализируется при обращение к классу или при создании экземпляра, поэтому возможна данная конструкция `[UIColor greyColor]`. А экземпляр класса инициализируется только при его создании.
Добавлю еще:

В методы экземпляра "-" компилятор за нас добавляет переменную `this` (ссылку на экземпляр), а в методы методы класса `"+"` (в других языках их называют статическими) он этого не делает, поэтому внутри него нельзя обратится к экземпляру.

Comment: Почти верно. Только добавляется не this, а self, и есть он везде, из "статических" методов тоже можно обращаться к self, который вернет метакласс текущего класса.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct objc_class {         
    struct objc_class *isa; 
    struct objc_class *super_class; 
    const char *name;       
    long version;
    long info;
    long instance_size;
    struct objc_ivar_list *ivars;

#if defined(Release3CompatibilityBuild)
    struct objc_method_list *methods;
#else
    struct objc_method_list **methodLists;
#endif

    struct objc_cache *cache;
    struct objc_protocol_list *protocols;
};
```

Наверное, так будет понятней, что имеется в виду под объектом класса. http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-208/runtime/objc-class.h

Answer (score -1):

Ничем не отличается. Это синонимы. 
"Шаблоном" или "описанием объекта" является класс, а "объект" представляет "экземпляр" этого класса. 
[Источник](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.1.php)