# Какая разница между экземпляром и объектом класса?

Tags: java, ооп

Столкнулся с казалось бы простым вопросом, но понял, что дать ответ на него не смог бы.

Какая разница между экземпляром и объектом класса? Java начал недавно изучать да еще и сам. В общем, определенное время думал, что это одно и тоже. Можно с примером, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет этот ответ по C#: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514799/106

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что это какие-то разные термины. Разница на уровне того, что "экземпляр" всегда будет иметь в виду конкретный объект, а просто "объект" может подразумевать случайный экземпляр.

Comment: @Etki, спасибо, учту Ваш ответ

Comment: Хм, вплоть до этого момента я считал, что это синонимы, но [аналогичный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2723/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) заставляет начать сомневаться. Разве что можно еще так сказать: "Объект — сущность в адресном пространстве ЭВМ, появляющаяся при создании экземпляра класса."

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличается экземпляр от объекта?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520287/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это одно и то же!

> Термины «экземпляр класса» и «объект» взаимозаменяемы.

([https://ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)))

Answer (score 1):

Никакой. Это синонимы. 
"Шаблоном" или "описанием объекта" является класс, а "объект" представляет "экземпляр" этого класса. 
[Источник](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.1.php)