# Java-классы. Объекты и экземпляры

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток Не могли бы вы простыми словами объяснить разницу между понятиями **объект класса** и **экземпляр класса**?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519461/191482 - если угодно непосредственно Java

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что-то сомнительно закрывать вопрос по джаве как дубликат вопроса по objective c...