# В чем разница между классом, объектом и экземпляром?

Tags: ооп, классы, объекты

Никак не могу понять, в чём разница между объектом и классом. У меня есть предположение, что  класс - это что-то общее, то есть, обширное понятие, а объект - что-то более узкое. Что касается экземпляра и объекта, так я думаю, что это одно и то же. Буду очень благодарен, если вы поможете мне разобраться.

Comment: В каком языке используется?

Comment: @RomanC а что в разных языках программирования понятия класса объекта или же экземпляра разные?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какая разница между экземпляром и объектом класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519461/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: @SeeSharp концептуально везде примерно одно и тоже.

Comment: @Suvitruf я тоже так думаю, тогда к чему первый комментарий?

Comment: @SeeSharp `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Ну вот и я `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @SeeSharp Смотря *что* вы понимаете под понятиями "класса объекта или же экземпляра". В некоторых языках они есть в некоторых есть частично, в некоторых отсутствуют, но это не значит, что они немогут быть реализованы. Поэтому я спросил, к какому языку относиться реализация, чтобы было понятнее о чем идет речь. Если это язык моделирования, например UML то желательно привести примеры на этом языке.

Comment: Вот теперь мои глаза открыты))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 8):

**Класс** - некая абстракция, логическая структура, описывающая поведение и характеристики. Например, машина. Она может ехать, сигналить и т.п.

**Объект** - конкретный экземпляр класса. Например, конкретная ваша машина.

**Экземпляр** класса - это одно и тоже, что и объект класса.

```
| № |           Объект           |                    Класс                             |
|:-------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------:|
| 1 | Объект - экземпляр класса  |  Класс - шаблон, по которому создаются объекты       |
| 2 | Сущность из реального мира |  Группа похожих объектов                             |
| 3 | Физическая сущность        |  Логическая сущность                                 |
| 4 | Объект СОЗДАЁТСЯ           |  Класс ОПИСЫВАЕТСЯ                                   |
| 5 | Объект можно создавать,    |  Класс определяется единожды                         |
|     как правило, много раз     |                                                      |
```

**Класс**: фрукт, **Объект**: киви, банан, манго.

Comment: Разве правильно говорить не характеристики, а состояние?

Comment: @MikeMclaren у класса нет состояния, состояние только у объектов.

Comment: А чем тогда отличаются характеристики от состояния?

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно подметил пользователь `Suvitruf` понятия класс и объект очень тесно связаны между собой.

### **Что такое класс и его экземпляры?**

Давайте приведем пример на ситуации из подобного `C` ЯП C# а далее будет рассмотрен пример из реальной жизни.

---

```
class Human
{
    string Name = "Human";
}
```

---

Здесь мы объявили `класс`. Что же мы сделали объявив класс?? Мы создали шаблон сущности который в дальнейшем мы можем использовать для создания новый `экземпляров класса`. Вот тут мы зададимся вопросом (которым Вы собственно и задались). А что такое `экземпляр класса`?? Это некий конкретный объект который может уже применяться изменяться как Вашей душе угодно. В примере выше, я объявил класс `Human`. Давайте же сейчас создадим его экземпляр:

---

```
Human concret_human = new Human();
```

---

Теперь после создания экземпляра класса, мы можем проводить какие либо манипуляции которые возможно применить к данному классу. Какие? Это уже от класса зависит. Проще говоря, класс это некий шаблон, который может использоваться для создания новый объектов или как у бородатых умных дядей экземпляров какого либо класса.

### Пример из реальной жизни

Теперь давайте попробуем привести пример из реальной жизни. Вы крупный инженер сотовых телефонов. Что бы сделать новую `конкретную` модель телефона, Вам нужно иметь шаблон в роли которого в программировании выступает класс. В шаблоне указано что каждый телефон должен звонить, включаться, выключаться и принимать звонки например. И по шаблону мы уже делаем конкретный объект который уже что-то может изменять в себе или использовать по назначению.

### Итоги

Давайте подведем итоги.

1. Класс - это некий шаблон, который предоставляет абстрактный вид любого объекта.
2. Объект или Экземпляр класса - это уже конкретная сущность которая сделана по шаблону класса.

Answer (score 0):

На собеседованиях можно и нужно сказать, что никто не называет "объектом" экземпляр класса, если не хочет запутать. Нет устоявшейся терминологии. Легко можно в разговоре назвать класс объектом, например "вот у нас есть такой объект Fruit, порождаемся от него и..."

Короче говоря есть класс и экземпляр класса, а объект как строгое понятие существует только в головах некомпетентных интервьюверов.