# Чем отличается экземпляр от объекта?

Tags: c#, классы, объекты

Чем отличается экземпляр класса от объекта класса в С#? И подскажите какую можно почитать литературу по данному вопросу.

Comment: Уже есть ответы на данный вопрос. Почему нельзя их поискать для начала? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2723  и еще http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514783   ..... аналогичные вопросы заданы 2 дня назад и 5 апреля.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Первый вопрос - про Objective-C, а тут C#. Второй вопрос - про другое, различие экземпляра и объекта там не раскрыто.

Comment: @PavelMayorov но ведь по факту оно одно и то же, нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский принятый ответ по первому вопросу говорит о таком термине как *`class object`*. Но в C# его нет (есть *`type object`* - но там нет слова *`class`*), и путать экземпляр не с чем.

Comment: можно почитать Г. Шилтд С# Базовый курс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно почитать на MSDN.

[Класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9afc042.aspx) - это логическая структура, позволяющая создавать свои собственные пользовательские типы путем группирования переменных других типов, методов и событий. Класс подобен чертежу. Он определяет данные и поведение типа. Если класс не объявлен статическим, то клиентский код может его использовать, создав *объекты или иначе экземпляры*, приписанные переменной. Переменная остается в памяти, пока все ссылки на нее не выйдут из области видимости. В это время среда CLR помечает ее пригодной для сборщика мусора. Если класс объявляется статическим, то в памяти остается только одна копия и клиентский код может получить к ней доступ только посредством самого класса, а не переменной *экземпляра*.

[Определение класса или структуры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173110.aspx)  подобно чертежу, на котором указаны действия, выполняемые типом.  В сущности, объект является блоком памяти, выделенной и настроенной в соответствии с чертежом.  Программа может создать множество объектов одного класса.  *Объекты также называют экземплярами*. Они могут храниться либо в именованной переменной, либо в массиве или коллекции.  Клиентский код — это код, использующий эти переменные для вызова методов и доступа к открытым свойствам объекта.  В объектно-ориентированном языке, таком как C#, стандартная программа состоит из нескольких динамически взаимодействующих объектов.

[Класс, загруженный в память, называется объектом или экземпляром.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ey4ke239(v=vs.90).aspx)

Из книг можно почитать:

1. **CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework** - *Джеффри Рихтер*
2. **Язык программирования C# 5.0 и платформа .NET 4.5** - *Эндрю Троелсен*
3. **Программирование на C# 5.0** - *Йен Гриффитс*

Достаточно хорошие книги для профессионального изучения C#.

Comment: Так отличие экземпляра от объекта-то в чем? Кажется, автором был задан конкретный вопрос...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, важные части своего ответа я выделил. К примеру: *Класс, загруженный в память, называется объектом или экземпляром*. Перейдя по ссылкам и почитав документацию можно понять, что это одно и то же. Просто кто-то называет экземпляром, а кто-то объектом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я просто подумал, что нужно дать более развернутый ответ, чтобы человек задавший вопрос не просто знал, что это одно и то же, а знал немного больше и, возможно, понимал - почему.

Answer (score 3):

Различие в том, что "экземпляр класса" - устоявшийся термин, а "объекта класса" не существует. Есть просто термин "объект".

В языке C# эти два понятия означают одно и то же.

Comment: ЕМНИП, не совсем

Comment: @Mirdin если что-то знаете - пишите ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Экземпляр это "штука" типа, а объект "штука" класса. Учитывая что класс можно определить как пользовательский тип, то можно сказать "экземпляр инт", а "объект инт" уже будет семантически не верно (хотя и распространено). Но тут надо сказать, что терминология в компьютерной сфере является жутко холиварной темой, поэтому можете считать вышеуказанное моим ИМХО и использовать экземпляр и объект как синонимы.

З.Ы. К ответу @Pavel Mayorov. Так как объект является единицей класса, то выражение "объект класса" является тавтологией.

Comment: Класс нельзя определить как пользовательский тип, потому что класс - это ссылочный тип.

Comment: Кстати, "объект класса" - это не тавтология. В таких языках как Java и Python это понятие имеет свой смысл, отличный от просто "объекта".

Comment: @PavelMayorov 1. MS с вами не согласны, тут выше давалась ссылка на msdn. Что конечно не отрицает, что в .Net классы - ссылочные типы. 2. Надо сказать что в С# различие между классом и типом стерлись почти до полного неразличения.

Comment: А как это относится к static class? Например в Reflection нет понятия класс. Есть тип. В Delphi например есть метаклассы

Answer (score -4):

Объект(чаще всего используем `new`):

```
SPList list = new SPList();
```

Екземпляр:

```
list.add(item);
```

В принципе одно и тоже, но не совсем.
[тыц №1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173171.aspx),   [тыц №2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2723/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0), [тыц №3](https://toster.ru/q/4847), [тыц 4](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level5/5_1.php)

и [теория](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9afc042.aspx):

> Класс — это логическая структура, позволяющая создавать свои
>   собственные пользовательские типы путем группирования переменных
>   других типов, методов и событий. Класс подобен чертежу. Он определяет
>   данные и поведение типа. Если класс не объявлен статическим, то
>   клиентский код может его использовать, создав объекты или иначе
>   **экземпляры**, приписанные переменной.

Comment: ну вот в приведённой Вам же цитате `создав объекты или иначе экземпляры` прямо говорится, что понятия объекты и экземпляры - это одно и то же, только разными словами!

Comment: а во второй ссылке @kirelagin объясняет нюансы перевода понятия 'class object'. По этому я посчитал возможным при ответе учесть все варианты и подкрепить эту информацию ссылками.